# invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference golang database

Tags: mysql, go

I searched a lot to find solution for this error, but nothing worked. when I use the query inside main function it works fine, but when I pass it to the Group function it panics. here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

var db *sql.DB
var err error

type Row struct {
    Id         int
    Title      string `json:"title,omitempty"`
    Adress     string `json:"adress,omitempty"`
    Tozihat    string `json:"tozihat,omitempty"`
    Mobile     string `json:"mobile,omitempty"`
    Phone      string `json:"phone,omitempty"`
    Mapid      string `json:"mapid,omitempty"`
    Location   string `json:"location,omitempty"`
    Keywords   string `json:"keyword,omitempty"`
    Imagepath1 string `json:"imagepath1,omitempty"`
    Imagepath2 string `json:"imagepath2,omitempty"`
    Category   string `json:"category,omitempty"`
    Catid      int    `json:"catid,omitempty"`
}

func Group(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    u := req.URL.RequestURI()
    Id := strings.Split(u, "/")[2]
    catId, errconv := strconv.Atoi(Id)
    if errconv != nil {
            fmt.Println(errconv)
    }
    rows, errrows := db.Query("select title, location, category from Total where catID=(?)", catId)
    if errrows != nil {
            fmt.Println(errrows)

    }

    defer rows.Close()
    var results []Row
    var result Row

    for rows.Next() {

            errr := rows.Scan(&result.Title, &result.Location, &result.Category)
            if errr != nil {
                    fmt.Println(errr)

            }

            results = append(results, result)
    }
    fmt.Println(results)
    jsonresults, errj := json.Marshal(results)
    if errj != nil {
            fmt.Print("error marshaling results", errj)
    }
    res.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    res.Write(jsonresults)

}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/group/", Group)

    http.ListenAndServe(":9001", nil)

    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:456852@/bartarinha")
    if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer db.Close()
    errPing := db.Ping()
    if errPing != nil {
            fmt.Println(errPing)
    }
}
```

any help is appreciated. the error looks like this: 
    2017/10/09 22:43:44 http: panic serving [::1]:41618: runtime error: 
    invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
    goroutine 7 [running]:
    net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0xc420088820)
        /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1721 +0xd0

```
panic(0x688060, 0x81fc40)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:489 +0x2cf
database/sql.(*DB).conn(0x0, 0x7fe580, 0xc4200102b0, 0x1, 0x6dac6a, 
0xd10000000000000e, 0xe)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:896 +0x3a
database/sql.(*DB).query(0x0, 0x7fe580, 0xc4200102b0, 0x6e7aff, 0x3b,                 
0xc420047aa8, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc42002cc00, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1245 +0x5b
database/sql.(*DB).QueryContext(0x0, 0x7fe580, 0xc4200102b0, 0x6e7aff, 
0x3b, 0xc420047aa8, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc4200e01a0, 0xc42003ca40, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1227 +0xb8
database/sql.(*DB).Query(0x0, 0x6e7aff, 0x3b, 0xc42003caa8, 0x1, 0x1, 
0x8, 0xc4200d8038, 0xc420016e40)
    /usr/local/go/src/database/sql/sql.go:1241 +0x82
main.Group(0x7fe080, 0xc4200f82a0, 0xc42000a900)
    /home/behrooz/gp_projects/src/samples/kabootar/main.go:40 +0x230
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x6e9d38, 0x7fe080, 0xc4200f82a0, 
0xc42000a900)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1942 +0x44
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x8293c0, 0x7fe080, 0xc4200f82a0, 
0xc42000a900)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2238 +0x130
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0xc4200942c0, 0x7fe080, 0xc4200f82a0, 
0xc42000a900)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2568 +0x92
net/http.(*conn).serve(0xc420088820, 0x7fe540, 0xc420014940)
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:1825 +0x612
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    /usr/local/go/src/net/http/server.go:2668 +0x2ce
```

Comment: You're not handling errors, you're just printing them out.

Comment: `http.ListenAndServe` blocks. None of the code afterwards actually runs.

Comment: Also, in some cases `http.ListenAndServe` can return an error. You should check for that. But JimB is correct, you are printing errors, but not handling them properly. My guess is that something returns `nil, error`, and you print the error and then blithely assume that the data value (which is nil) is good anyway. Without seeing more of your program's output we can't really say for sure.

Comment: The stack trace shows the line number where the panic happened. Look for a line in `Group`. That will probably point to the problem.

Comment: I tried to print out the errors to see if any thing appears in out put instead of panic. The http.ListenAndServe works fine, I tested it without using database related codes and also the query works fine if i put it in main function. I think the error comes from sharing db *sql.DB ...

Comment: @BehroozAhadian: no, Peter's comment describe the problem precisely. If `ListenAndServe` didn't block your problem would just exit, and you can't initialize `db` if you don't execute that code. Your program will still likely crash later however unless you start handling the errors too.

Comment: Somehow I missed that the DB wasn't initalized until after the call to `ListenAndServe`... Oops. The error handling issues will certainly come back go bite you later though, exactly as described in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the crash is caused by the db pointer being nil. This means code which tries to use that connection on line 40 causes a panic.

```
rows, errrows := db.Query(...
```

The db pointer is nil because, as Peter pointed out, http.ListenAndServe is blocking, which means **nothing** after it will run.

Try running this example locally to see the problem:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func Group(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    println("group handler")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/group/", Group)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9001", nil)
    if err != nil {
      panic(err)
    }
    println("Running code after ListenAndServe (only happens when server shuts down)")
}
```

You won't see the Running code message.

Comment: Thank you every one, your answers gave me insight. Finally I replaced the http.ListenAndServe to the bottom of the code to escape the block.